# Regex filename matching with a delimiter

Tags: regex

I need to use regex to extract the hostname from the following directory path. Basically, host1, host2, host3, host4, host5 and host 6.

```
/opt/var/logs/2015/08/04/03/host1_syslog.log
/opt/var/logs/2015/08/04/03/host2_syslog.log
/opt/var/logs/2015/08/04/03/host3_syslog.log
/opt/var/logs/2015/08/04/03/host4_applog.log
/opt/var/logs/2015/08/04/03/host5_applog.log
/opt/var/logs/2015/08/04/03/host6_applog.log
```

Working on the problem, I have managed to match up to the filename without extension:

```
([^\/]+)(?=\.\w+$)
```

ie. **host1_syslog**

But not the hostname:

ie. **host1**

I have not been able to figure out how to stop the match after it encounters the underscore character **_**.

Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
([^\/]+)(?=_[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.\w+$)
```

You can use this .Under `lookahead` added `_[a-zA-Z0-9]+` explicitly.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/11

Answer (score 2):

This matches after the last slash up to the underscore:

```
(?<=\/)(?!.*\/)[^_]+
```

The whole match is the host name (no need for groups).

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/VlJcESke1J).

Answer (score 0):

Edit 2:

I think this might work -- Greedily work through everything up to and including the last slash, then capture everything until the underscore:

```
  '.*/([^_]+)'
```

Edit 3:  (adding Python re example)

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.compile('.*/([^_]+)').search('/opt/var/logs/2015/08/04/03/host1_syslog.log').groups()
('host1',)
```